# Gradle build failure after upgrading to Android Studio 2.1 from 1.5

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-2.1

After upgrading to Android Studio 2.1 from 1.5, my application is giving errors on Gradle build like `app:DebugResources`:

> [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task '`:app:mergeDebugResources`'.
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > -1